# How to get a reference to an object in a .nib file?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nib, iboutlet

so far I have done most view programming in code, but it really is cumbersome to position buttons perfectly in code. I searched for some time, maybe I'm using the wrong words for my search? Anyway, I created a UI in a nib file, it has several buttons. I loaded the .nib file into my view like this:

```
NSArray* nibViews =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UCMenuView" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *menuView = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
self.delegate = (id<UCMapviewDelegate>)delegate;
// another controller does the view switching, so I'm sending him the view  
[self.delegate pushView:menuView];
```

This is 'fine'. But I don't understand how I get a pointer to my buttons. I know about IBOutlet, but how do I connect them to the elements in the .nib? How would I connect this `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *calendar;`
 to a specific button in the .nib?

I tried to ctrl-drag (from that little points on the left side of the @property, but that does not work (from neither side). Excuse me if this is an easy question, but I couldn't find a clear explanation

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Instead of just a `UIView *menuView`, you need to create a custom
   UIView subclass for that, e.g. `UCMenuView`. Define your properties on this custom
   class.
2. Open your .xib file in the editor, select the **File's Owner** in
   the left column and set its **Custom Class** in the identity
   inspector to `UCMenuView`.
3. Right-click the **File's Owner** in the left column, and connect
   your IBOutlets.

Comment: and I guess this class must inherit from UIView?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html
or
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ios-development-guide-part2-your-first-app/

Kind regards, 
Bo

Answer (score 0):

See Apple's documentation: [Creating and Connecting an Outlet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/CreatingOutlet.html) and more generally [Designing User Interfaces in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html).

Comment: The links are broken